# Using Apache XML RPC and Commons JARs in Android

Tags: android, jar, xml-rpc

Is it possible some how to include the Apache XML RPC and Apache common **jar** files in an android project?

Comment: you ask about how to integrate these jar files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [Apache XML RPC](http://apache.mesi.com.ar//ws/xmlrpc/) and 
      [Apache common](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=download+Apache+XML+RPC+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#pq=download+apache+xml+rpc+&hl=en&cp=26&gs_id=v&xhr=t&q=download+apache+commons+jar&pf=p&sclient=psy&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=download+apache+commons+ja&aq=0&aqi=g1g-v1g-j1g-b2&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=1d753b302b4e010e&biw=1280&bih=905).

1. Eclipse -> Android Project -> Properties -> JavaBuildPath -> Libraries -> Add External Jars -> 
      select jars where downloades on your system -> OK

So, simple. :-)